# save symbol under point to kill ring upon pressing isearch-forward-symbol-at-point

Tags: isearch, symbols, kill-ring

I want `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` to also save to the `kill-ring`. How can I accomplish that please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```lisp
(defun my-isearch-forward-symbol-at-point ()
  "`isearch-forward-symbol-at-point', but copy symbol name to `kill-ring'."
  (interactive)
  (isearch-forward-symbol nil 1)
  (let* ((bounds  (find-tag-default-bounds))
         (string  (and bounds  (buffer-substring-no-properties
                                 (car bounds) (cdr bounds)))))
    (cond
     (string
      (kill-new string)
      (when (< (car bounds) (point))(goto-char (car bounds)))
      (isearch-yank-string string))
     (t
      (setq isearch-error "No symbol at point")
      (isearch-push-state)
      (isearch-update)))))

(define-key isearch-mode-map "." 'my-isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)
(define-key search-map       "." 'my-isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)
```

All I did was copy the definition of `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` and insert a call to `kill-new`.

Comment: thanks but how is this to be invoked? after hitting C-s and then .  isearch just searches for  . occurences. I would rather have the copying as a side effect of hitting M-w .

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code I forgot the `(kill-new string)`, which puts the `string` into the `kill-ring`. Please try the updated code.

Comment: thank you, but how can I automatically invoke this when pressing M-s . isearch-forward-symbol-at-point ? I dont want to have to press C-s .

Comment: I added the binding to `search-map` as well. You can also add it to `query-replace-map`...